# Printing through vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 2 page sheet in excel that I want to print through vba. Here's what I want vba to do:
- Print the first page exactly at the range I want it to "A1:P38"
- Print the second page "A39:P82" back to back with the first page (which means I need to give the print command in a single line?). The front and back page lines should match, which I have verified they do, if it prints out the correct range.

Currently what is happening is that when I try to print out the range "A1:P82", it prints "A1:P37" on the first page and the rest on the second. When my colleague tries to print, it prints "A1:P39" on first page and the rest on the second. Any ideas? I have attached the sheet I want to print. When I try to print, it prints the first page one row less and when my friend tries to print, it prints one row more in the first page. In both cases, the page matching is thrown off. It needs to print first page only until row P38.
My code is attached below. There are 2 checkboxes: to select whether to show preview or print directly, another to choose whether user wants to see notification messages.
[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowLast As Integer
Dim pages As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim bins As Integer
Dim count As Integer

rowLast = Sheets("Kanban Print").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
bins = Sheets("RecManip").Cells(4, "B").Value
If rowLast = 1 And CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Common error: Nothing to print."
End If
pages = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((rowLast - 1) * (bins / 2), 0)

For i = 1 To pages
    Sheets("RecManip").Cells(1, "B").Value = i
    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        Range("A1:P82").PrintOut preview:=True
    Else
        Range("A1:P82").PrintOut
    End If
Next

If rowLast > 1 And CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox (rowLast - 1) & " cards printed for " & bins & " bin system."
End If

Sheets("RecManip").Cells(1, "B").Value = 1
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with your current approach...

Comment: @Verzweifler Edited.

Comment: Use [actual page breaks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-ad3dc726-beec-4a4c-861f-ed640612bdc2) and print `From:=1, To:=1` and `From:=2, To:=2`?

Comment: Are these two different commands? If I give two separate print commands one below the other, they print on two separate pages instead of back to back.

Comment: I assumed you manually reuse the sheet to print on the other side. If your printer supports duplex, just print `From:=1, To:=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gserg:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowLast As Integer
Dim pages As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim bins As Integer
Dim count As Integer

rowLast = Sheets("Kanban Print").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
bins = Sheets("RecManip").Cells(4, "B").Value
If rowLast = 1 And CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Common error: Nothing to print."
End If
pages = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((rowLast - 1) * (bins / 2), 0)

For i = 1 To pages
    Sheets("RecManip").Cells(1, "B").Value = i
    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        Range("A1:P82").PrintOut preview:=True
    Else
        Sheets("Kanban Card template").PrintOut From:=1, To:=2
    End If
Next

If rowLast > 1 And CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox (rowLast - 1) & " cards printed for " & bins & " bin system."
End If

Sheets("RecManip").Cells(1, "B").Value = 1
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```